# RXNORM database schema Flat files contered to a MySQL database (cannot figure out the relationships)

Tags: mysql

I've been given a MySQL database that supposedly originated from RXNORM flat files.

After several days of pulling my hair out, I cannot determine the relationships between most of the tables.

I cannot find a database schema anywhere that provides the relationships between the tables.

The online documentation is not providing useful help.

Does anybody have experience working with RXNORM files or converting the files to a RDBMS format?

RXNORM is a acronym for the National Institute of Health

The database given to me contains duplicates and is not normalized.

Comment: You'll get better results, and be more helpful to future users, if you formulate a clearer question - something like "how can I figure out the relationship between databases converted from RXNORM format?" See [ask].

Answer (score 3):

Check out the NIH website: https://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/umls/rxnorm/overview.html
It specifically states that it is not normalized:

> The full monthly RxNorm release includes 9 data files, which are simple text files with pipe ('|') delimiters between each field value. RxNorm data files are meant to be loaded as separate tables into a database management system. However, the files are not fully normalized as would be the case in a formal database; there are duplications across and within files by design.

They also have other information regarding how to query the database:

https://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/umls/implementation_resources/query_diagrams/er3.html
https://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/umls/implementation_resources/query_diagrams/er6.html

I'm still looking specific examples, I've been successful in writing some scripts. Were you able to do so?